# Neo4j node property arrays to create relationships

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, cypher

I'm really enjoying Neo4j but I'm stuck on this small problem. My data has Movie nodes, Actor nodes and ACTED_IN relationships. For example:

```
(a:Actor {name: 'Leonardo DiCaprio'})-[r:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie {name: 'Titanic'})
```

But some movies have the actors nested as a comma delimited array in a property called cast. For example:

```
(m:Movie {name: 'Oceans Eleven',  
   cast: 'George Clooney,Brad Pitt,Andy García,Julia Roberts,Matt Damon'})
```

How do I convert the cast properties into unique ACTED_IN relationships?

Comment: For formatting see: [Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query needs to use **SPLIT()** and **UNWIND**:

```
MATCH (m:Movie {title: 'Oceans Eleven'}) 
WITH m, SPLIT(m.cast, ',') AS list_actors
UNWIND list_actors AS actor
MERGE (m)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(:Actor{name: actor})
```

And then you can check the result:

```
MATCH p=(m:Movie {title: 'Oceans Eleven'})-[]-(n) RETURN p
```

[image]

Comment: If I don't want to CREATE multiple Oceans Eleven nodes. Do I simply use MERGE instead?

Comment: You can replace the last line with: "CREATE (m)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(:Actor{name: actor})" to avoid creating duplicate `Movie` nodes. However, if the relationship already existed, a duplicate relationship would be created. Changing `CREATE` to `MERGE` would solve the latter problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach, which also avoids creating duplicate nodes and relationships:

```
MATCH (m:Movie {name: 'Oceans Eleven'})
FOREACH(c IN SPLIT(m.cast, ',') |
  MERGE (a:Actor {name: c})
  MERGE (a)-[r:ACTED_IN]->(m)
);
```